# Play upgrade to 2.4 but failed to fetch sbt-plugin

Tags: playframework-2.3, playframework-2.4

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.4.0 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
```

This is my plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Typesafe Snapshots" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/",
  "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
)

// The Play plugin

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Play Framework 2.4` is not yet available, however you can use release candidate. For latest releases, check `Play Framework` [github home page](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/releases).

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.0-RC5")`

Edit: `Play Framework 2.4` is now available.